# Slide manipulation in PowerPoint with C#

Tags: c#, office365, powerpoint

I am trying to make a PowerPoint add-in using C#.

I would like to add a panel with a button and when I click the button, a new slide is added at the end of the current presentation.

No problem with adding the panel and the button, but I can't make the function to add a slide.
I have found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slides-addslide-method-powerpoint) where they propose this:

```
Public Sub Add_Example() 

   Dim pptSlide As Slide 
   Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout 

   Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout 
   Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout) 

End Sub
```

But it is for VBA.
Do you know the equivalent in C# that can add a slide to the current presentation ?

Comment: This has several answers around the internet.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slides.add(v=office.14).aspx
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7762e105-d392-423b-807e-af50869cf86d/add-a-slide-to-a-power-point-show-using-c-wpf?forum=officegeneral
And it is about the same in C# as it is in VBA, if you're using Interop.

Comment: The first link you give recommands to use **Slides.Add (number, layout)** but how do you specify the object **Slides** ? The 2nd link permits to modify another file, but my problem is to modify my current presentation. I think my problem is I don't know how to translate the VBA **ActivePresentation** into C#